# Read files with bundle in unit tests

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I want to parse json with unit test.

But I couldn't find the file. When i run it normally i can find the file. But when I unit test, I can't find it. What do you think is the problem?

*Below is the code and screenshot.*

```
    func testExample() throws {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct
        // results.
        let bundle = Bundle(for: MusicifyAPITests.self)
        guard let url = bundle.url(forResource: "music", withExtension: "json") else {
            print("not found!")
            return
        }
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let decoder = Decoders.plainDateDecoder
        let music = try decoder.decode(Music.self, from: data)
        print(music)
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DPW8.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a Swift Package. First, make sure you're copying these resources into the bundle. For example:

```
.testTarget(
    name: "MusicifyAPITests",
    dependencies: ["MusicifyAPI"],
    resources: [
        .process("music.json"),
    ...
```

See [Bundling Resources with Swift Package](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package) for more details.

Then use `Bundle.module` to access it:

```
let bundle = Bundle.module
...
```

Comment: amazing stuff, you saved!